# get value of function in json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jsonp

I'm tring to get some json to contain a function so that the option in the plugin gets the returned value of the function that was in the json string.

The set up is as such:

default.txt

```
    [
        {
            "element":"a[href$='.jpg']",
            "options":{
                "label":"test"
                }
        },{
            "element":"a#hover",
            "options":{
                "label":(function(ele){ return 'test'; })()
            }
        }
    ]
```

and the plug-in is

```
(function($) {
    function defined(obj){return typeof(obj)!=='undefined';}
    function evaluate(ele, obj) {
        if(typeof obj === 'function') {
            //alert('is function');
            obj = obj(ele);
        }else{
            try{
                //alert('thinking it may be a function still');
                obj = eval("("+obj+"("+ele+"));"); 
                //obj = (obj)(ele);
            }catch(err){
                //Handle errors here
                //alert('not function');
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
    function debug(message) {
          console.debug(message);
    }
    $.set = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({}, {}, options);
        if(defined(settings.actions)){
            $.each(settings.actions, function(index, value) { 
                $(value.element).do_action(defined(value.options)?value.options:null);
            });
        }   
    }

  $.fn.do_action = function(options) {
    // Add event handler to all matching elements
    return this.each(function() {
        var ele = $(this);
            var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.do_action.defaults, options);
            var label= evaluate(ele, settings.label);

            var message = "label:'" + label + "'";
            debug('Tracking ' + action + ' ' + message);
    });
  };
  $.fn.do_action.defaults = {
    label         : function(ele) { return ele.attr('href'); }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

and the control is

```
$.getJSON('default.txt' , function(data){
    $.set({
        actions:data // this si where we pull in the options
    });
});
```

I seems to work if I put in an alert inside the anonymous function, so from

```
"label":(function(ele){ return 'test'; })()
```

to

```
"label":(function(ele){ alert('test') })()
```

but after that I can't seem to get it to print right in the console as I only get the message

```
Tracking label:'(function(ele){ return 'test'; })
```

**[EDIT]**
Please stop saying that "you should not put code in json".  If you work for Google and are their top level programmers getting paid the big super bucks then I'll listen to the why's, but I'm sorry if it's good for them, it'll work for me.  Don't know what else to say, I already understand the point of why you should avoid it which I aim to do as well.  There are times when you just can't and why i supect Google does the same.

Comment: json should not be code - just data.

Comment: just a heads-up - you have a couple of places where you've misspelled "label" as "lable"

Comment: fixed the label tk . to bad it anit that as the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `label` member is not a function; it's a value returned by a function.  The final `()` at the end means "execute this function immediate whenever the value of `label` is requested and provide its return value as the value of `label`".

That said, if you must include functions in your JSON object (and from what you've said, you do) your best bet is to stringify-and-eval your functions.  You should also be able to use raw functions in your JSON, like {foo : (function(){ ... }) }, though I've personally had a tricky time getting this right (but that's just me -- if you can get it right, go for it).

(As an aside, it's not possible to stringify functions from existing objects, but if you're getting your functions as text from user/programmer input, that's not an issue.)

Comment: I'm sorry I am not following your question here.. yes it's self executing function that is to retrun the string back, which is doesn't, but when used as an alert it do the alert.

Comment: Edited. The alert happens because label is always run.  The final "resolved" value of label is a string.  Any time you ask for the value of label, that anonymous function runs, and returns "test" as the value for label.

Comment: so simple removing the () does not solve the issue.. truning (function(ele){ alert('test'); }) in to function(ele){ alert('test'); } also doesn't help..

Comment: Definitely keep the outer parens; those are needed for `eval` to read the function correctly.  From here, I'd do a debug output for `typeof obj` and find out how your code sees `label`.  I'd also include an `alert` along with a `return` so you can test that the function runs and that it returns correctly.

Comment: so.. the trick is...... turn "label":(function(ele){ return 'test'; })
 into "label":"function(ele){ return 'test' }" .. force it to be a string till the very end when it hit eval.  At that it then properly works.. So the answer is  drop the () to invoke the function at parse of the json string and turn the function into a string fully, then it works.

Comment: @apsillers did you remove my edit?  the anwser is not correct till that edit is applied.

Comment: The answer here is simply, “to pass a function you have one of two options depending, stringify-and-eval your functions OR use (function(){  }) ”..  I highly disagree that part of the answer is "this decision is that it doesn't make sense .." It’s not an idiotic move to need to take in a function from JSON. I discussed it with 5 of my peers at the university where I do my Dev work.  It's agreed that there are many times where it’s the only way to transvers the DOM and/or the event propagation scope correctly. Yes all in moderation. I would say this opinion with the final answer is not correct.

Comment: You are correct -- my comment is only tangential to your situation.  You are parsing a function *from* JSON, which is possible; I state that stringifying a function *into* JSON is not possible.  I will clarify the statement in my answer.

Comment: Super, thank you for understanding... It's worth noting that it seems that you can stright pass the function as (function(){ })()  and it does work, thou as it's prased.  But I guess that is more a note to  others.  Thanks for helping work out the solution.  Cheers -